# Setting up Android project to work for team source control

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

I've got myself a doozy of an issue with my first real Android project.

So, I've got my new and very basic Android project setup in Intellij IDEA, and it's working great on my local machine. I'm able to build and export to my emulator just fine.

The problem occurs when my team member tries to import the project from our GIT repository. All the files are there, and he imports the project using the 'Existing' choice from IDEA.

Here's our GIT project structure:

```
libs
res
src
.gitignore
AndroidManifest.xml
README.md
ic_launcher-web.png
proguard-project.txt
project.properties
```

What happens is that when he imports the project, IDEA is not able to resolve the project's dependency on *appcompat_v7*.

I've gone through every post I could find relating to import issues on SO and via Google Search, but we still cannot resolve this issue.

Any Android pros out there have any idea why this is happening? I'd really appreciate it!

We've already wasted hours trying to figure this thing out :(

Comment: How about using Android Studio (based on IDEA) and Gradle? Gradle makes managing dependencies a lot easier :)

Comment: That's what we decided to go with based on your and Jerry's recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely recommend Android Studio and its concise gradle build files.

Perhaps the quickest approach is to start a new project in Android Studio then bring in all your sources. (Is there a feature to convert to gradle?)

Here's my .gitignore file. It's long simply because it's the standard GitHub .gitignore with two additions at the top:

```
# Gradle temp files?
.gradle/

# Android Studio
/.idea/workspace.xml


#################
## Eclipse
#################

*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath


#################
## Visual Studio
#################

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml
*.pubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

#############
## Windows detritus
#############

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac crap
.DS_Store


#############
## Python
#############

*.py[co]

# Packages
*.egg
*.egg-info
dist/
build/
eggs/
parts/
var/
sdist/
develop-eggs/
.installed.cfg

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
.coverage
.tox

#Translations
*.mo

#Mr Developer
.mr.developer.cfg
```

Comment: We evaluated Android Studio before we chose IDEA, and we were concerned with its performance/stability.

With that in mind, do you still recommend it as the best choice for Android dev?

Comment: Yes. I haven't had any stability problems. The only issue I encountered is when it wants to self-update, I have to temporarily disable a Windows local group policy setting I added to block malware from running code in certain directories. -- It occurs to me that I haven't testing building from a clone of the project. I can do that in a few hours. If you want to test in the meantime, clone it from https://github.com/1fish2/BBQTimer

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. It looks like we got our project to work well with Android Studio. We still had to manually import the appcompat_v7 library, but it worked well afterwards :).

Comment: Glad to help. BTW my cloned repo works fine in Android Studio. I didn't try on another computer.

Comment: Just my tuppence : any gradle support in AS is going to be in intellij too. With AS a lot is "hidden" in order to make it easier for the adopter from what I can see. I'm yet to see any reason for anyone to use AS over intellij though : what little you gain is more than offset by what you lose (ie Android only in AS). This isn't a swipe at AS, far from it, but certainly support will be far more available for intellij than for its more Android styled cousin.

Comment: JetBrains has an FAQ on that http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/ . Are all of Android Studio's plug-ins available for IntelliJ now?